# How to clone a django reporsitory into a virtualenv

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv, bitbucket

I've got a virtualenv set up for a django app. So far I've installed all my packages via pip when the virtualenv is activated, but I now need to clone one from bitbucket. Is there a special way to do this or do I just need to open a terminal, goto venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages and run the clone command?

Here's the repository i'm trying to clone https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/src

Comment: OT: would you mind to add the information - what you want to clone- to your headline?

Comment: @reporter the actual repository?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-e` flag and specify a git repo:

```
pip install -e git://github.com/manojlds/mylib.git#egg=mylib
```

The url above can be bitbucket, github etc.

> `-e, --editable <VCS+REPOS_URL[@REV]#EGG=PACKAGE>`
>                                 Install a package directly from a checkout. Source will be checked
>                                 out into src/PACKAGE (lower-case) and installed in-place (using
>                                 setup.py develop). You can run this on an existing directory/checkout
>                                 (like pip install -e src/mycheckout). This option may be provided
>                                 multiple times. Possible values for VCS are: svn, git, hg and bzr.

Comment: Can't get this to work, I've updated my answer to show the actual repository I'm trying to clone. `--editable=hg://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/src is not the right format; it must have #egg=Package`

Comment: @KingFu - Follow what I have given. In the end of the url, there is a `#egg=mylib`. Append similar to your url. In your case add `#egg=python-amazon-product-api`

Comment: @KingFu - The following command works for you - `pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api#egg=python-amazon-product-api
`

Comment: ah didn't see I had to change Package to the actual package name. Now im getting a error with full stack trace `    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'python-amazon-produ\xe2\x80\x8c\xe2\x80\x8bct-api', 'at', '\xe2\x80\x8c\xe2\x80\x8bct-api')`

Comment: @KingFu - That is beyond the scope of the question. It got installed right?

Comment: couldn't get it installed with your syntax, but changed it to `pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/` and it worked perfect. if you updat your answer i'll award you  the answer

Answer (score 0):

clone repository,

- if your app is has `setup.py`, then run `python setup.py install`
  when virtual env is actived.
- else copy this app inside you django project and add name of it your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

or you can use `pip install -e <repo_addr>`, see [doc](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-install).

Comment: Can't get this to work, I've updated my answer to show the actual repository I'm trying to clone. `--editable=hg://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/src is not the right format; it must have #egg=Package`

Comment: this package exist on pypi, why don't use `pip install python-amazon-product-api`?

Comment: that isn't the latest version, the one on pypi contains bugs